# programatically button pressed event not working in swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboard

pressed on button pushviewcontroller will not  to go otherVC.

code is given below please i want some suggestion i am new in swift .

## first i tried this

```
@IBAction func f_pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

            let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Webview") as! Webview
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
        print("RUNNN")

    }
```

## second i tried this

```
 @IBAction func facebook_pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
            //Instantiate SecondViewController
            let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Webview") as! Webview
        print("pass")
            // Set "Hello World" as a value to myStringValue
            secondViewController.urlstring = ""
          print("pass1")
            // Take user to SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
          print("pass2")


    }
```

Comment: xcode matter in this?, because i m using xcode 7.2

Comment: Are you sure your first view controller in embedded in navigation controller.If not you can't push to any other controller

Comment: I think you should past the error for us. sometime maybe your navigaitoncontroller is nil, or you wrong declare storyboard.

Comment: @Vikky ,@Leang Socheat thank for this guysnow it work properly